# Latex compilation very slow

Tags: compiling, ubuntu

I have a recent installation of Ubuntu 22.04 on which pdflatex takes around 50 secs to compile a document. The exact same document on another computer but with 18.04 takes less than 2 secs to compile.

Before upgrading to 22.04, similar or even bigger sized documents would compile in around 2 to 3 secs on my cumputer.

I have tried compiling in Texstudio and also from terminal. Both are equally slow.

Would you know why latex compilation so slow now?

**Update (06 July 2023):**
I added the path to the texlive distribution to TEXINPUTS after which the compilation time sped up by a factor of 2. The compiler still stops to search for certain files but for most of the other it finds them quickly. It still take around 25 secs to compile but this is much better than before. On the other machine where latex the same file compiles in 2-3 secs, the path to the tex-live distribution is not included in TEXINPUTS.

Is it normal to have to add the path of texlive to TEXINPUTS? Or is this something new with the newer releases of texlive?

Comment: check that TEXINPUTS is not including a large directory tree that is not pre-indexed with `ls-R` files. If tex has to search the filesystem for each file it's a lot slower

Comment: Yes, please show us the output of `kpsexpand \$TEXINPUTS`.

Comment: also which latex release do you have on each system, this may be relevant: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/1060

Comment: kpsexpand  \$TEXINPUTS just has one directory (local) that I always had. It has a few stylefiles that do not ship with the standard distribution

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: on 22.04 it is Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex). I do not have access to the other computer right now but it is older (earlier than 2020).

Comment: no, the latex version,  eg current release is: `LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-16>`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: could you please explain in layman's term what is being discussed in the github link you refer to? Since I am not really an expert in this I am having trouble parsing. I presume it refers to files being cached but I am not sure how should I react.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Firstly, thanks for your quick replies. How can find out the release. When I run latex --version, it gives the output I wrote earlier. It always runs pdftex even when I run latex.

Comment: @user137846 a latex release added some features around file loading but had a worse than intended impact on speed, especially with documents with lots of small input files. It was fixed in the release following that PR So my first comment is the "standard answer" but if you are using the latex release subject to that issue there may be a specfic fix that can be back ported

Comment: the banner dates I show are on the terminal and log file of every latex run

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the tip! Here is the release info: LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for the explaining what is discussed in the link. Indeed, I am compiling a document in book format with individual files for the chapters. Each chapter is around 10 pages. Could this be the reason behind the slowdown? Also, should I update the latex release and see whether the problem goes away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am answering my own question for the record.

Our internal system administrative staff helped solve this issue. In my TEXINPUTS there was a directory that was mounted through NFS. This directory slowed down the compilation for some reasone. Once I copied its contents locally, the compilation times became normal.

Answer (score 1):

On my box, the reason for extremely slow Latex was that the source files live in a directory with 15k+ files.

Given that the current directory is included in resource search, and that it is not pre-indexed, this results in horrific performance.

The current workaround is to introduce sub folders.

Thanks David for your useful comment!